# Why does node.js readFileSync() not return what writeFileSync() wrote?

Tags: node.js, fs

I have this code running on Node.js

```
fs.writeFileSync (filePath,  s );
let s2 =  fs.readFileSync (filePath);
```

After the code executes 's2' is not 's'.  's' is a String whereas 's2' is a Buffer.  I know, I can make them the same by adding 'utf8' as the second argument to readFileSync().

My question is why was the API written so that I need to pass'utf8' to readFileSync() but NOT to writeFileSync()? What is the benefit of that?  To me it would  make intuitive sense  that what you write  is what you get back when you read the same file.

Is there perhaps some underlying  fact about character encoding or Unicode I am  missing?

Answer (score 1):

`writeFileSync` accept a string or a Buffer as its first argument for convenience. `readFileSync` needs to pick one or the other to return and since the file itself doesn't know what kind of data was written to it, there's no way to tell what data type was originally used in the `writeFileSync` call that created the file. Since raw binary data (the file contents) is not well-defined without the additional information of the encoding, the default is Buffer (which is a representation of the raw bytes), while specifying an encoding provides the missing information and the function is then able to interpret the raw data into a string.